# Progress Message

Tags: oracle-adf

How to add a progress message like "Fetching Data" pragmatically. When the data is getting fetched , i need to display this message on the blank page.I am new to ADF , so pardon me if it is some thing very basic . I couldn't find it on net.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use javascript in your page or pagefragment. My example uses a page fragment, so the id of the popup must contain the region. If you have trouble locating the correct id you can look it up from any browser, by using View Source, and searching for the name you gave it (in this case splashPopup).

```
    <af:resource type="javascript">
      function enforcePreventUserInput(evt) {
          var popup = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId('pt1:r1:0:splashPopup');
          if (popup != null) {
              AdfPage.PAGE.addBusyStateListener(popup, handleBusyState);
              evt.preventUserInput();
          }
      }

      function handleBusyState(evt) {
          var popup = AdfPage.PAGE.findComponentByAbsoluteId('pt1:r1:0:splashPopup');
          if (popup != null) {
              if (evt.isBusy()) {
                  popup.show();
              }
              else if (popup.isPopupVisible()) {
                  popup.hide();
                  AdfPage.PAGE.removeBusyStateListener(popup, handleBusyState);
              }
          }
      }
    </af:resource>
```

The popup inside the pageFragment. It displays a simple gif animation of a spinning circle. You can find numerous other animations if you need to on google.

```
<af:popup id="p1" contentDelivery="immediate">
                    <af:dialog id="d2" type="none" closeIconVisible="false" title="Loading">
                        <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl5" layout="vertical" halign="center">
                            <af:image source="/images/loading.gif" shortDesc="Loading data..." id="i1"/>
                        </af:panelGroupLayout>
                    </af:dialog>
</af:popup>
```

Now, I think you will want to show the popup during a long running query or some other long running process, after pressing a button or an image link. For this you must define a clientListener on your component, which uses the javascript methods defined above.

```
<af:commandImageLink text="Test LongRunning Query" id="cil1" icon="/icons/excel.jpg"
                                         action="#{myBean.doStuff}"
                      <af:clientListener method="enforcePreventUserInput" type="action">
                      </af:clientListener>
</af:commandImageLink>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have a long running method call then you can call that method on page load

```
<af:serverListener type="onloadEvent"
                         method="#{backingBeanScope.initBean.callMethod}"/>
 <af:clientListener type="load" method="triggerOnLoad"/>
 <af:resource type="javascript">
        function triggerOnLoad(event)
        {
          AdfCustomEvent.queue(event.getSource(), "onloadEvent", {},false);
          return true;
        }
  </af:resource>
```

and then use adf status indicator to show the status on the page.

```
<af:panelStretchLayout id="psl1" startWidth="33%" endWidth="33%"
                                   topHeight="33%" bottomHeight="33%">
          <f:facet name="bottom"/>
          <f:facet name="center">
            <af:statusIndicator id="si1"/> 
          </f:facet>
          <f:facet name="start">
            <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl2"/>
          </f:facet>
          <f:facet name="end">
            <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl3"/>
          </f:facet>
          <f:facet name="top">
            <af:panelGroupLayout id="pgl4"/>
          </f:facet>
</af:panelStretchLayout>
```

Refer to this blog post fro more details 
[Show status indicator for long running method calls - ADF](http://adftidbits.blogspot.com/2014/11/show-status-indicator-for-long-running.html)